# Airflow Dynamic Task mapping - DagBag import timeout

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I have a DAG that fetches a list of items from a source, in batches of 10 at a time, and then does a dynamic task mapping on each batch. Here is the code

```
def tutorial_taskflow_api():

    @task(multiple_outputs=True)
    def get_items(limit, cur):

        #actual logic is to fetch items and cursor from external API call
        if cur == None:
            cursor =limit+1
            items = range (0, limit)
        else:
            cursor = cur+limit+1
            items = range(cur, cur+limit)

        return {'cursor': cursor, 'kinds': items}
        
    @task
    def process_item(item):
        print(f"Processing item {item}")

    @task
    def get_cursor_from_response(response):
        return response['cursor']
    
    @task
    def get_items_from_response(response):
        return response['items']
    
    cursor = None
    limit = 10
    while True:
        response = get_items(limit, cursor)
        items = get_items_from_response(response)
        cursor = get_cursor_from_response(response)

        if cursor:
            process_item.expand(item=items)
        
        if cursor == None:
            break

tutorial_taskflow_api()
```

If you see, I attempt to get a list of items from a source, in batches of 10, and then do a dynamic task mapping on each of the batch.

However, when I import this item, i get the Dag Import timeout error:

```
Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/Test.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/decorators/base.py", line 144, in _find_id_suffixes
    for task_id in dag.task_ids:
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/timeout.py", line 69, in handle_timeout
    raise AirflowTaskTimeout(self.error_message)
airflow.exceptions.AirflowTaskTimeout: DagBag import timeout for /opt/airflow/dags/Test.py after 30.0s.
Please take a look at these docs to improve your DAG import time:
* https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.5.1/best-practices.html#top-level-python-code
* https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.5.1/best-practices.html#reducing-dag-complexity, PID: 23822
```

How to solve this?

I went through the documentation and found that executing the While loop logic shouldn't really be there, but in some other task. But if I put that in some other task, how can I perform dynamic task mapping from inside that other task?

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```py
    while True:
        response = get_items(limit, cursor)
        items = get_items_from_response(response)
        cursor = get_cursor_from_response(response)

        if cursor:
            process_item.expand(item=items)
        
        if cursor == None:
            break
```

is running in the `DagFileProcessor` before creating a DAG run, and it's executing every `min_file_process_interval`, and each time Airflow retry to run a task in this dag. Airflow has some timeouts like `dagbag_import_timeout` which is the maximum duration the different `DagFileProcessor` have to process the dag files before a timeout exception, in your case if you have a big batch, or the API has some latency, you can easily exceed this duration.

Also you are considering `cursor = get_cursor_from_response(response)` as a normal python variable, but it is not the case, where the value is not available before creating a dag run.

### Solution and best practices:

The Dynamic Task Mapping is designed to solve this problem, and it's flexible, so you can use it in different ways:

```py
import pendulum

from airflow.decorators import dag, task


@dag(dag_id="tutorial_taskflow_api", start_date=pendulum.datetime(2023, 1, 1), schedule=None)
def tutorial_taskflow_api():
    @task
    def get_items(limit):
        data = []
        start_ind = 0
        while True:
            end_ind = min(start_ind + limit, 95)  # 95 records in the API
            items = range(start_ind, end_ind) if start_ind <= 90 else None  # a fake end of data
            if items is None:
                break
            data.extend(items)
            start_ind = end_ind
        return data

    @task
    def process_item(item):
        print(f"Processing item {item}")

    process_item.expand(item=get_items(limit=10))


tutorial_taskflow_api()
```

But if you want to process the data in batches, the best way is the mapped task groups, but unfortunately the nested mapped tasks is not supported yet, so you need to process items in a loop:

```py
import pendulum

from airflow.decorators import dag, task, task_group


@dag(dag_id="tutorial_taskflow_api", start_date=pendulum.datetime(2023, 1, 1), schedule=None)
def tutorial_taskflow_api():

    @task
    def get_pages(limit):
        start_ind = 0
        pages = []
        while True:
            end_ind = min(start_ind + limit, 95)  # 95 records in the API
            page = dict(start=start_ind, end=end_ind) if start_ind <= 90 else None  # a fake end of data
            if page is None:
                break
            pages.append(page)
            start_ind = end_ind
        return pages

    @task_group()
    def process_batch(start, end):
        @task
        def get_items(start, end):
            return list(range(start, end))

        @task
        def process_items(items):
            for item in items:
                print(f"Processing item {item}")

        process_items(get_items(start=start, end=end))

    process_batch.expand_kwargs(get_pages(10))

tutorial_taskflow_api()
```

### Update:

There is the conf [max_map_length](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#max-map-length) which the maximum number of parallel mapped tasks/task group you can have. If you have some picks in your API, you can increase this limit (not recommended) or calculating the `limit` (batch size) dynamically:

```py
import pendulum

from airflow.decorators import dag, task, task_group


@dag(dag_id="tutorial_taskflow_api", start_date=pendulum.datetime(2023, 1, 1), schedule=None)
def tutorial_taskflow_api():
   @task
    def get_limit():
        import math
        max_map_length = 1024
        elements_count = 9999 # get from the API
        preferd_batch_size = 10
        return max(preferd_batch_size, math.ceil(elements_count/max_map_length))

    @task
    def get_pages(limit):
        start_ind = 0
        pages = []
        while True:
            end_ind = min(start_ind + limit, 95)  # 95 records in the API
            page = dict(start=start_ind, end=end_ind) if start_ind <= 90 else None  # a fake end of data
            if page is None:
                break
            pages.append(page)
            start_ind = end_ind
        return pages

    @task_group()
    def process_batch(start, end):
        @task
        def get_items(start, end):
            return list(range(start, end))

        @task
        def process_items(items):
            for item in items:
                print(f"Processing item {item}")

        process_items(get_items(start=start, end=end))

    process_batch.expand_kwargs(get_pages(get_limit()))

tutorial_taskflow_api()
```

Comment: The main reason I wanted to process in batches is that the size of all the items in list can exceed max XCOM size and the number of batches can be huge. So, will the XCOM size be a limitation in the second approach? I believe it can be a limitation in the first approach but not sure of the second one.
And thanks for taking the time to help! Cheers!

Comment: I just updated my answer to handle this case